# Node Discord Bot Api Stock Quote

Tags: javascript, api, discord, discord.js, response

Hello I am wondering if there are any syntax errors in the following code which would prevent the symbol, name, and price from pulling through:

```js
if (command === 'getQuote') {
    let getQuote = async () => {
    let response = await axios.get(
        'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote/AAPL?apikey=demo'
    );
    
    let quote = response.data
        return quote
    };
    let quoteValue = await getQuote();
    console.log(quoteValue);
    message.reply(
        `Heres your quote\n${quoteValue.symbol}\n\n${quoteValue.name}\n\n${quoteValue.price}`
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're getting an array back from the API, but you're treating the `quoteValue` as an object instead.

Check this codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-dan-4nc4m?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thank you so much. I see it printing in console in the sandbox, but still nothing in Discord. You can see in these images, the joke code is the same, but working - https://imgur.com/SOizv3m ... https://imgur.com/b3KrjiF

Comment: Thank you. This does work. Apparently changing getQuote to getquote worked as the command?